# Decode a signed cookie in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, decoding

So I have a signed cookie that has the following value

```
IjVvVGdIOW1pUU44Qkk5NFZZUl9Udnci--a3c3b748fd207ba1c537b590dd458b4855677146
```

I need to decode it and get the following value

```
5oTgH9miQN8BI94VYR_Tvw
```

I tried something like

```
Base64.decode64(cookie_value.split('--').first)
```

but it gives me the wrong value, it adds these damn slashes in the string so I end up with

```
"\"5oTgH9miQN8BI94VYR_Tvw\""
```

Comment: what is `cookie_value`? How are you creating it? is it from some gem?

Comment: no, sorry, the cookie value is the value of the signed cookie, the first string in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it gives me the wrong value, it adds these damn slashes in the
>   string so I end up with
>
> `"\"5oTgH9miQN8BI94VYR_Tvw\""`

Its not adding any slashes. The issue here is your returned string is included between double quotes `"`. `\"` here is escape character.

Here:

```
Base64.decode64 "IjVvVGdIOW1pUU44Qkk5NFZZUl9Udnci"
# => "\"5oTgH9miQN8BI94VYR_Tvw\""
puts Base64.decode64 "IjVvVGdIOW1pUU44Qkk5NFZZUl9Udnci"
# "5oTgH9miQN8BI94VYR_Tvw"
```

As the problem is unwanted `"`s. You can remove them as follows:

```
Base64.decode64(cookie_value.split('--').first).chomp('"').reverse.chomp('"').reverse
# => "5oTgH9miQN8BI94VYR_Tvw"
```

Comment: why does it add these escape characters?

Comment: I suppose you're using Rails 4.x. From Rails 4.0, cookie-based sessions are serialized in JSON format. JSON representation of a simple string is to wrap its value in double quotes.

Comment: the problem is its adding quotes. escape characters are what you see as raw data. I have updated my answer to remove quotes.

Comment: I suggest using `Oj.load(double_quoted_string)` to remove quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
require 'rack'

puts Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64::Marshal.new.decode("IjVvVGdIOW1pUU44Qkk5NFZZUl9Udnci")
```

Also you can decrypt it.

```
Marshal.load(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(the_cookie_value.split("--").first)
```

Comment: I used the second way on the other project, but now I am getting "incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)" error

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following:

```
MultiJson.load(Base64.decode64(cookie_value.split('--').first))
```

probably works only with rails 4.1 +, although I am not sure